# I cannot centre elements using Bootstrap and there are problems with the radius of one div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am trying to do a login form using HTML and Bootstrap but I can't get to align all elements in centre. They seem to be in centre but the header which is centre aligned by Bootstrap is not in one line vertically with the other elements. I am using the Grid and I need the elements to be centre-aligned in medium and small screen. In medium screen I tried to follow the logic of 12 column of the grid so to fill spaces until I arrive in centre but still the elements are not aligned correctly.

Also I can't apply the desired radius to login form. I need it to be more rounded. Bootstrap doesn't seem to work. CSS does but it applies radius to all the divs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" >
    <title>Social Network</title>
</head>

<body class="bg-primary">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-3 col-md-6"></div>
        <header class="text-center fs-3 text-white my-5">
            SOCIAL NETWORK
        </header>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2 col-md-4 m-1"></div>
    <div class="rounded-3 text-center bg-light p-4 col-centered col-8 col-md-3 px-5">
        <div>
            <input type="email" class="form-control my-5" id="inputUsername" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Username">
            <input type="password" class="form-control my-5" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <button type="submit my-5" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center my-4 text-secondary">OR</div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <a class="text-decoration-none link-secondary" href="">Forgot Password?</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-1 col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-1 col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="text-center text-secondary rounded-pill col-8 col-md-3 bg-light my-4 py-3" id="signUp">
        <div class="text-centered">Don't have an account?    <a class="text-primary px-3" href="">Sign Up</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1 col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've mocked up a simple example for you based on your Div boxes and layout.  In short you can use.

There's a couple of things to not here.  The ***centering*** is achieved by using Flex and justifying the content to the centre - *d-flex justify-content-center*

As for the border radius, I've added a rule called ***login-box***, which sets the radius to 20px.

Hope that helps.

```css
.login-box {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.new-user-box {
  border-radius: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" >
    <title>Social Network</title>
</head>

<body class="bg-primary">

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <header class="text-center fs-3 text-white my-5">
        Social Network
    </header>
</div>
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center ">
    <div class="col-6 login-box">
    <div>
                <input type="email" class="form-control my-5" id="inputUsername" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Username">
                <input type="password" class="form-control my-5" id="inputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit my-5" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center my-4 text-secondary">OR</div>
            <div class="text-center mb-4">
                <a class="text-decoration-none link-secondary" href="">Forgot Password?</a>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="text-center text-secondary col-6 bg-light my-4 py-3 new-user-box" id="signUp">
        <div class="text-centered">Don't have an account?    <a class="text-primary px-3" href="">Sign Up</a></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked. Do you know how to set the width of "Don't have an account?" div the same as the login form. As per now they are in centre but "Don't have an account" div is smaller than login form. I tried css width but the div gets out of the centre field.

Comment: I'm not sure that you mean because the widths are set by col-6, for both the login form and the new user.  I've updated my answer above to include your login form.  Are you talking about the width of the content _inside_ the div boxes?